# QuickBlox Chat Swift Integration

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, quickblox

I am trying to integrate QuickBlox Chat in my swift application. I have followed some initial steps to integrate the framework. I'm not using pod. QuickBlox suggests to use sample code for the same. Its sample code shows LoginTable where we select one user to login. But I have seperate login view in my app. How can I simply login with user email or user name and password, and what views I need to import from sample code. I am new to chat feature. Please help!

[image] I am getting error message Required session does not exist. Please help

Comment: Please illustrate in steps

Comment: Your Question is not clear enough. Please make it more clear by providing steps

Comment: ok, 1. I downloaded and inserted the QuickBlox.framework file into my project. 2. Linked all the frameworks mentioned in http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework. 3. Then, I registered my account on http://quickblox.com/signup/ and created an application, got all the keys and enabled the cloud backend for my iOS app. 4. Now, I've made a login page in my app with User Name, Email ID and Password for registration. 5. I want to register and open a page with all users list added to my account.

Comment: Question is How to use User Name, Email ID and Password to enter my application's quickblox account. I need some initial steps with swift code.(for manual framework, not for pod)

Comment: How to call quickblox login API with these parameters?

Comment: @Goddard please help!

Comment: kindly follow the link http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Adding_a_User_Base_to_your_application

Comment: @Goddard please click on the above image link (I've edited the original post, image link is added below the post, click it to open the image). I am getting an error message "Required session does not exist". Kindly help